# Python os.listdir() doesn't return some files

Tags: python

I have a python function that checks the modified time of a folder using `os.stat()` and then it does a `os.listdir()` of that folder.

I have another process which create files in the folder being checked.
Sometimes it is observed that three files are created with same timestamp and the folder's stat also has the same timestamp.

When the python function fetches the the files in the same millisecond, it is observed that `os.listdir()` is providing only 2 of the 3 created files.
Why is this so ?

The environment is :

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6

Python Version: Python 3.6.8

Filesystem : xfs

Sample code

```
import os
import sys
import time

filelist=list()
last_mtime=None


def walkover():
    path_to_check="/path/to/check"
    curr_mtime=os.stat(path_to_check).st_mtime_ns
    global last_mtime
    global filelist
    if last_mtime == None or curr_mtime > last_mtime:
        for file in os.listdir(path_to_check):
            if file not in filelist:
                filelist.append(file)
        last_mtime = curr_mtime
        print ("{} modified at {}".format(path_to_check, last_mtime))
```

The function is invoked to maintain a list of files at a point of time.
The if case is present to avoid multiple `os.listdir()` invokations.

Edit:

The files are ".rsp" files which gets created by ninja when a ".o" is about to get built.

Since my machine has multiple cores (16), the ninja is triggered from cmake with "--parallel 16" . This will cause 16 compilations to happen parallely .

Comment: So the Python process is listing files at the same time as the other process is creating them? Isn't it just that the last file hasn't been created yet then?

Comment: It is a possibility, but the stat output of all the 3 files and the folder are same even upto the last nanosecond

Comment: Are you sure the files are actually flushed to the filesystem at that point in time? Just because one process has created/written the files does not mean they are actually on the filesystem, but may still be in the OS' buffer.

Comment: Your sample code only includes *reading* the files, not *writing* them – since this appears to be a timing issue, the latter part should be relevant as well. Please take a look at [mcve]. Also take note that ``walkover`` is an O(n^2) algorithm (``for file in os.listdir(path_to_check):`` works on all ``n`` files, ``f file not in filelist:`` compares against all previously seen ``n`` files) – it is likely not an optimisation as such. Consider just to completely recreate ``filelist[:] = os.listdir(path_to_check)`` whenever the directory changes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : As I understand, even if file is not flushed to the disk, the file will still be visible to all the processes (which have access) in the os.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this ninja thing but it seems to me that when writing the first ".rst" file and running the walkover function are executed at approximately the same time the walkover function may be missing out on the creation of the other files. Wether it's buffers or queues or whatever, specifically when parallel processes are in play the order of events can be hard to grasp.

Comment: Welcome to the site Danny! Can you edit your question into question format? Currently you're describing a situation without asking what you need help with. Please also give as much detail as you can on what you have tried, what research you've already done, etc. so we can address your actual issue without guessing.

It would probably help to include the code context sample as well.